# instance has no attribute '__str__'

Tags: python, exception, tostring

When attempting to convert an object to string (when logging in this case), it sometimes (extremely rarely) fails with the given error. When should I expect this behaviour?

The offending line in myobj:

```
log.warning("Instance is %s", self)
```

is throwing a stacktrace which ends in:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
exceptions.AttributeError: myobj instance has no attribute '__str__'
```

This is very odd as while `myobj` does **not** have a `__str__` method, calling `str` on it works as expected, and this log line works as expected when I manually test it. IE I've been unable to reproduce this.

What could cause this behaviour? A search on google for the title of this question yields less than 1 page of results, which leads me to believe this is a 1-in-a-million race condition with a garbage collector or something.

Comment: Interesting problem. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Kevin -- I would guess python2.6 from the stacktrace ;-)... But I suppose I could be wrong.

Comment: If you `str()` an object without the `__str__` method, it will give you the `__repr__` method.

Comment: does it have a `repr`?

Comment: is `myobj` of a C extension type?

Comment: @Kevin, mgilson was correct: python 2.6.6

Comment: @Antti Haapala, it does not have a __repr__. 
`myobj` inherits from twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory, which should be a normal python class. I had a quick look at the source for that and it doesn't define a str or repr either.

Comment: Weird. Even an old-style class instance without `.__str__` or `__repr__` defined won't fail if you call `str()` on it, but I do get that error message with  `class Test(): pass` `print(Test().__str__())`.